# imread couldn't find image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, imread

I use visual studio 2013 and opencv. I run a simple code that reads a image and shows it. I add the image to resource files of my project from Donloads file. When I run below code, `image.data` is empty.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
  #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
 #include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

cv::Mat image;
image = cv::imread("im.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
{
    std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

cv::namedWindow("Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

cv::waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Most probably the current directory is not what you think it is.  Try using full path for the file, and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried C:\\Users\pr\Downloads\im.png and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try : `C:\\Users\\pr\\Downloads\\im.png` that should work if the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default working directory in VS is the location of your `vcxproj` file (value of `$(ProjectDir)`).

If you would like to start your application through VS (i.e. by `F5` key) then you should overwrite the debugging parameters of your project. For example you can set the application's working directory to the location of the program (exe) that the linker creates by setting the value of `Project menu -> Properties -> Configuration properties -> Debugging -> Working directory` to `$(OutDir)`.